# Simulate keyboard keypress in currently active HTML input by on-screen element click - input focus must not change

Tags: javascript, html, forms

For web apps I'm using mobile devices with barcode scanners for ASP.NET web form apps. The devices only have numeric hardware keyboard. No letters.
But users need to be able to additionally type three different letters "F", "Q" and "K" which I want to add as on-screen buttons.
Each window of the application has multiple HTML "input" boxes.

The press of a letter "button" from the on-screen button should

- behave exactly like a physical keyboard - add the letter at the right of the currently active HTML input, don't change focus.
- not cause any post-backs or page reloads

I want to avoid using Javascript frameworks and I'd like to stick to standard html/css/javascript.

While there are similar questions there is a substantial difference - they don't care about input focus.

Comment: "_behave exactly like a physical keyboard - add the letter at the right of the currently active HTML input_": That's not exactly how keyboards and input events work, but it's fine as a problem constraint. In reality, it's more complicated — e.g. there is a selection (cursor position/range) and inputs insert/overwrite the selection.

Comment: This seems like it might be a simple problem to solve, but in order to deliver a considerate user experience, you're going to need a lot more code than is appropriate for a question on SO. See [ask] for more info on Q/A scope.

Comment: Thank you. The methods described there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically cause the html input to loose focus. But I need it to exactly behave like a keyboard - focus must not change while typing.

Answer (score -1):

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802455/20298765 I found a workable solution that doesn't loose focus when using the on-screen keys.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
             .btn {border-style: solid;}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>    
    <script>
        var selectedInputId;

        function clickBtn(key) {
            if (selectedInputId != null) {
                selectedInputId.value = selectedInputId.value + key.innerHTML;
                selectedInputId.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div class="btn" onclick="javascript:{clickBtn(this)}">F</div><br/>
    <div class="btn" onclick="javascript:{clickBtn(this)}">Q</div><br/>
    <div class="btn" onclick="javascript:{clickBtn(this)}">K</div><br/>
    

    <input type="text" id="id1" onfocus="javascript:{selectedInputId=this;}" />
    <input type="text" id="id2" onfocus="javascript:{selectedInputId=this;}" />
    <input type="text" id="id3" onfocus="javascript:{selectedInputId=this;}" />
    <input type="text" id="id4" onfocus="javascript:{selectedInputId=this;}" />
</body>
```

Comment: This solution works well since almost a year but I need to add backspace functionality. I tried the suggested  solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863823/simulate-backspace-button-js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735518/how-might-i-simulate-a-backspace-action-in-a-text-field but these solutions will loose input focus.
Can I achieve that as well like the key presses without loosing input focus?